# Exchange 2007: Block external email for user except for distribution group

Tags: windows, exchange-2007

I have a user who is a member of a distribution group.

Currently the user and the distribution group can both receive external email.

I would like the user **not** to receive external mail sent to his own address, only to receive external mail sent to him via the distribution group.

In the users mailbox properties - Delivery Restrictions, I have tried the "only senders in the following list" and adding the distribution group, and also the "require that all senders are autheticated" setting. However when I enable these settings, email is blocked when addressed to the user (as expected) but also email sent to the distribution list.

How do I acheive this in Exchange 2007 ?

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is a workaround.
See if you can create a mailbox to be used as a 'forwarder' only mailbox. Make this new mailbox a member of the distribution list. 
From the mail flow settings -Configure the new mailbox to accept messages only from the certain addresses (then specify unique address- only senders in the following list). 
In delivery options of the new mailbox select forward to - and put in the recipient who is not allowed to receive external email.Then remove the recipient who is not allowed to receive external email from the distribution list.
I did have time to test the workaround, I hope this helps.